# GridView SelectedIndexChanged - return item that was clicked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have an ASP.NET DataGrid that returns three clickable columns at the end. When running SelectedIndexChanged how can I return the value of the item that was clicked?

Thanks

[image]

```
  Private Sub DG_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Try
        Dim DG As GridView = CType(sender, GridView)
        Dim vID As Integer = DG.SelectedRow.Cells(0).Text
        'Need to determine which item was clicked here
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm a little surprised that your code above doesn't work... pretty much what I would've done.

Comment: Here is an alternative way of doing it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: Zack - code works and returns the ROW that was selected but I need to know which link out of three columns was clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found the only way was to add an onclick event to the LinkButton

```
 AG_Link.Text = "View Agenda"
 AG_Link.Attributes.Add("onclick", "returnDocumentType('Agenda');")
```

Add some JavaScript to update a hidden textbox, then pick up the result

```
 Private Sub DG_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Try
        Dim DG As GridView = CType(sender, GridView)
        Dim vID As Integer = DG.SelectedRow.Cells(0).Text
        Dim DocumentType As String = DocumentTypeTB.Text

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

Bit of a long way round, but it works :-)